# HTTP 500 error: Unable to handle this request for wordpress website on AWS ec2

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I have a WordPress website[Bitnami Nginx sevrer] hosted on AWS ec2. I am facing this issue and cannot figure out what is causing it. There is one thing to note **I am able to access my WordPress Admin Dashboard**. I tried looking up online but all I find is "How to resolve Internal Server errors(HTTP 500)".

Here's what I have tried so far:-

- Disabled all the active plugins on WordPress but I still face the same issue.
- Tried to access the Nginx server logs but couldn't find anything there.

Also a couple of days back, I had modified `WP_DEBUG` to True in the `wp-config` PHP file and also specified my domain for the `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` parameters in the same file while hosting on my custom domain instead of using the Route 53 service. So could this issue be because of that?

Comment: the first thing you should do is to check the nginx error logs. what does your nginx error logs say?

Comment: > `Tried to access the Nginx server logs but couldn't find anything there.` - what do you mean? do you mean you couldn't find the error logs at all, or do you mean the error logs were empty?

Comment: @hanshenrik I first did `cd /opt/bitnami/nginx/logs` and after that, I ran `cat error.log` command and I could see the error logs. 
The last log is from **8th December 2020** which goes something like **[error] 4331#0: *30914 open() "/opt/bitnami/apps/bitnami/banner/htdocs//css/normalize.css" failed (2: No such file or directory)**.
What do you suggest I could do?

Comment: hmm that suggest php's errorlogs are not tied to nginx's error logs (usually with nginx+php-fpm, php's errorlogs are just redirected to nginx's errorlogs, but not with your setup), what do you get if you run `<?php var_dump(ini_get("error_log"),ini_get("log_errors"));`  ?

Comment: @hanshenrik I currently have an SSH connection to my ec2 instance. So should I try this command there?

Comment: probably won't work over ssh, when you run php directly from ssh, you run it from something called `php-cli`, and when you run it through your website, you run it through something called `nginx+php-fpm`, php-cli and php-fpm usually run 2 different configurations, you need the php-fpm configuration, not the php-cli configuration... still, you can try running `php -r 'var_dump(ini_get("error_log"),ini_get("log_errors"));'` and see what you get, you'll see the php-cli errorlog configuration; but that's not the config you want, you want the php-fpm configuration

Comment: @hanshenrik When I run  `php -r 'var_dump(ini_get("error_log"),ini_get("log_errors"));'` command in `/opt/bitnami/nginx/logs` I get the output as follows:- 
**string(0) ""
  string(1) "1"**
Also when I tried checking the Nginx server status using `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh status` command I can see output as **php-fpm already running**

Comment: so there's no special error_log setup for your php-cli, it just goes to stderr. but that's not the config we need, we need the config for your website, aka the php-fpm config. so for your website, make a new file called `foo.php` literally just containing `<?php var_dump(ini_get("error_log"),ini_get("log_errors"));` , then go to `your_website.com/foo.php`  , what do you get?

Comment: @hanshenrik Where should I create this PHP file? Any specific path?

Comment: yeah it has to be in your website's root dir, but where is that? it's a good question. you can probably find it by running `find / -iname 'index.php' 2>/dev/null` , what do you get from that? (also it might take a while to run, ESPecially if you're not running SSDs, or if you have some web mounts, sshfs etc)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225868/discussion-between-devansu-yadav-and-hanshenrik).